# How do i make TimeSpan start ticking in seconds?

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

How do i make my TimeSpan object tick in seconds?

```
private TimeSpan time;

public Clock{
    time = new Timespan(0, 0, 0);
}

public void Tick()
{
   //start ticking in seconds
}
```

Comment: A TimeSpan doesn't tick.

Comment: Really, then I've been lied to. What can i use to set a specific time and have it tick?

Comment: What do you mean by "have it tick"? You mean raise an event every X time period?

Comment: Timers usually have a tick event.  I don't know what platform you are using, or how accurate it has to be, so it makes it hard to offer advice.

Comment: Try `var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();`.

Comment: I'm creating a console digital clock. I want to set a time and call the tick method to have to make it count up in seconds, just like any ordinary clock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TimeSpan` is a data type used for storing time. However, you need a `Timer` if you want something to run/update at an interval. You can implement a `Timer` like so:

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

public class Clock
{
    private static Timer aTimer;
    private TimeSpan time;

    public Clock()
    {
        // Initialize the time to zero.
        time = TimeSpan.Zero;

        // Create a timer and set a one-second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Interval = 1000;

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

        // Start the timer.
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        time = time.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you create a `new Clock()` object, it will get its own `time` and update every second.

See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx) from MSDN for more information about the `Timer` class.